# В произвольной матрице n*n помогите найти сумму отрицательных чисел в 1 части (включая диагонали)

Tags: c, циклы, матрицы

В произвольной матрице n*n

```
 \ 1 /
4 \ / 2
  / \
 / 3 \
```

найти сумму отрицательных чисел в 1 части (включая диагонали)

Comment: 1) Выложите свои попытки решить задачу, иначе вопрос просто закроют. 2) Дополните свой вопрос понятным и конкретным условием задачи, примером входных данных, то что вернула ваша программа и то, что вы ожидали увидеть в результате.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
const int n = ...
int a[n][n];

// Заполнение матрицы

int sum = 0;
for(int row = 0; row < (n+1)/2; ++row)
    for(int col = row; col < n-row; ++col)
        if (a[row][col] < 0) sum += a[row][col];
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!